# Im getting an error "No such file or directory" when installing Composer Globally

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install Composer globally but I get an error when I do 
`sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`
The error reads

```
mv: composer.phar: No such file or directory
```

When I try and instal Laravel

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

And after I try to run

```
Laravel
```

I get

```
zsh: command not found: laravel
```

Comment: Might seem like a silly question, but did you download the composer.phar first and are running that command from the same directory in which it resides?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> [**From the docs:**](https://getcomposer.org/download/) 
>   *To quickly install Composer in the current directory, run the following script in your terminal.*

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'baf1608c33254d00611ac1705c1d9958c817a1a33bce370c0595974b342601bd80b92a3f46067da89e3b06bff421f182') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

> *You can place the Composer PHAR anywhere you wish. If you put it in a directory that is part of your PATH, you can access it globally.*
>   *After running the installer following the [Download page](https://getcomposer.org/download/) instructions you can run this to move composer.phar to a directory that is in your path:*

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

> **Note:** If the above fails due to permissions, you may need to run it again with sudo.

```
sudo mv.composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

> **Note:** On some versions of macOS the `/usr` directory does not exist by default. If you receive the error "`/usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or directory`" then you must create the directory manually before proceeding:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
```

> **Note:** For information on changing your PATH, please read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) and/or use your search engine of choice.

Comment: When ever I try and run Laravel, it just opens up its file

Comment: What do you mean _"run Laravel"_ ? Have you followed the [installation instructions](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/installation)? Running `laravel new blog` will _create_ a new Laravel project titled **blog**. You still need to serve the site - run `php artisan serve` to start a development server at `http://localhost:8000`. You can also use [valet](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/valet#installation).

Comment: Yes it worked thank you! In the tutorials I was watching they showed things appeared differently than what I had in the screen.  They also never mentioned php artisan serve, I did it and now im able to see the laravel page.

Comment: Awesome!! Congratulations :) Welcome to the wonderful world of Laravel! Laracasts are a great way to get your feet wet with the framework. Their [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x) is phenomenal as well.

Comment: Second note did it for me: on my new Mac with BigSur the bin folder within /usr/local/ was not there. Thanks.

Answer (score 85):

After composer is installed, I used the following command to create a alias for the composer file. So now its running globally.

```
alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer'
```

Now can try to run

```
composer
```

Comment: It worked, thank you Sir :)

Answer (score 6):

after installing composer as stated above, you have to move the composer.phar to the /usr/local/bin directory. to do this, first create the new directory by running the command:

> sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin

after that, move the composer.phar to the new path with:

> sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

Comment: Thank you. This helped me in macOS Monterey. This is the answer if you have permission problems (permission denied).

Comment: Thank you too for the commendation. I'm glad I could be of help

Comment: THAT's the right answer!!!!

Answer (score 2):

This command worked in creating a new directory:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
```

After I moved the `composer.phar` to the new directory using :

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

This command didn't work for me:

```
alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer'
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).